# why are the parameters put on the stack in this order

Tags: c#

When a caller puts the arguments to a function on the stack, the arguments are added
in reverse order, with the last argument highest on the stack, and the first argument
lowest on the stack. The callee then accesses these arguments using the base pointer,
with the first argument closest to the base pointer. Why are the parameters put on the
stack in this order?

Comment: Well, there must be -some- order. Why would that be worse than any other? (btw, for some optimized code, there's fastcall optimizations that actually uses registers for the most accessed parameters, instead of the stack)

Comment: **Stack** means exactly what you describe, otherwise it would have been a **Queue**

Comment: @CarbineCoder well, not really, they could push them in reverse order or something... I just fail to see why is that important :-)

Comment: I didn't get the question correctly :-) you are right

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer the question: by convention (that's why they are called "calling conventions").  There's no other reason that I know of.

Most compilers (in x86 at least), will push them from right to left. They could aswell do it from left to right (or randomly), but that wouldn't improve performance (or anything else) at all.

There's also `FASTCALL` calling convention which will try to optimize by putting the most accessed parameters directly in registers, instead of the stack (the rest of parameters which don't fit in registers would still be pushed from right to left in the stack).

"Original" fastcall is done by sending the first 2 (in x86... 6 in x64 if I remember correctly) parameters into registers... however I believe (I may be wrong) that C# does some kind of extra optimization to determine which are the most accessed ones and uses those instead of the "first two".